# How to prove that there exists $(a_0,\cdots,a_n)\in R^{n+1}$ such that for every polynomial $P\in R_{n-1}[X]$ one has $\sum_{k=0}^na_kP(X+k)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

The problem described in the title can be reformulated in several ways, but I am still unable to find a suitable proof or even an angle of approach… :

• if one defines $\phi(a_0,\cdots,a_n)$ in $L(\Bbb{R}_{n-1}[X]$ by $\phi(a_0,\cdots,a_n)(P)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kP(X+k)$, and by $\Theta$ the linear function $(a_0,\cdots,a_n)\mapsto \phi(a_0,\cdots,a_n)$, then the problem is to prove that $\ker\Theta\neq \{0\}$.

• another way of seeing this is to define $\phi_k: P\mapsto P(X+k)$, then the problem consists in proving that the family $\{\phi_k\}_k$ is linearly dependent in $L(\Bbb{R}_{n-1}[X])$

Comment: In fact $(\phi_k)=(\phi_1^k)_{k \geq 0}$. As $\mathbb{R}_{n-1}[X]$ has dimension $n$, its endomorphism space has dimension $n^2$ and thus some linear combination of the $\phi_k$, $0 \leq k \leq n^2$ must vanish. But it is a fact that in any endomorphism of a vector space of dimension $n$ has a vanishing polynomial of degree at most $n$ (Cayley-Hamilton theorem), so there is a linear combination of the $\phi_1^k$, $0 \leq k \leq n$, that vanishes. QED

Comment: Thank you for this solution, which is as short as it is elegant. However, I wonder whether there isn't a simpler one which does not involve Cayley Hamilton theorem.  Indeed, I found this problem in a 1st Year textbook, in the introductive chapter for Linear Algebra, so there must be a (undoubtedly longer) proof which doesn't use such a difficult result…

Comment: In fact, mentioning Cayley-Hamilton gives the idea of searching the eigenvalues of $\phi_1$. A short calculation shows that the only possible (complex) eigenvalue is $\lambda=1$, hence $\phi_1-id$ is nilpotent, which yields that, at least, one has $(\phi_1-id)^n=0$. Using the binômial theorem, one finds easily the adequate linear combination. The only problem with this solution is, once again, that it uses eigenvalue theory…

Comment: But there’s a simple way to avoid eigenvalue theory: you can check directly that $\phi_1-id$ decreases the degree of any nonzero polynomial, so that $(\phi_1-id)^n=0$ on the space of polynomials of degree less than $n$.